# Why does the while loop stop when condition check variable becomes 0?

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain me what happens down below?

```
var i = 5;
while(--i){
  console.log(i);
}
```

The thing is the while loop goes until 1 (console logs 4,3,2,1)

I know that if I check 1 or 0 for true I will get the following result

> 0 == true > false
>
> 1 == true > true

What I dont understand is what happens when the number is something like 4? How does that even work?

Since checking 4 for true will deliver the following result

> 4 == true > false

Comment: 4 is also a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value

Comment: It is starting with 5, and decrase with 1 in every step. When it 0, what means false, it stopped.

Comment: `console.log(Boolean(4))` returns `true`.

Comment: Only `0` is false. Everything else is true. The while loop basically takes the form: `while(--i > 0){ ... }`

Comment: @progy_rock Not only `0` -> [Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and the condition would be `while(Boolean(--i) == true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented above:

4 is a truthy value in javascript:

```
if (4) {
    console.log(true);    
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

this will print `true`

Another way to see this:

```
0 and true = false
1 and true = true
4 and true = true
```

Documentation for truthy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that translates to true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

The reason that `4 != true` is that the true value is coerced into a number. So infact `4 == true + true + true + true`

Answer (score 2):

Any non-zero number is treated as TRUE.

So in your loop, `i` starts as 5. On the first iteration `i` is reduced by 1 (by the `--i`), and the result (4) is tested to be TRUE. Thus it enters the WHILE loop and logs the value of `i` (4). The WHILE loop then returns to start and reduces the value of `i` by 1 again to become 3. This is also treated as TRUE and thus enters the loop again.

Only once `i` reaches 0 does it get treated as FALSE, and thus exits the WHILE loop.